# Cannot Delete Image From Unrestricted/Unlocked Document

Tags: microsoft-word

## Problem

I have an image in the header of a word document that I would like to remove.  It appears to be locked in a manner that avoids the usual unlocking methods (see below for what I've attempted). When I select the image and hit the delete key, I get a brief error in the bottom left corner stating: *You can't make this change because the selection is locked*.

[image: Displayed Message]

## Suspected Issue

My best guess is that this image or document has some XML setting that's not visible to the typical user. When I click on the `check for issues` method, it runs through the document and identifies something in the header.

[image: header check]

When I click `Remove All` it shows: *This fix did not complete successfully.*

[image]

## Unsuccessful Attempts

I've searched quite a bit and found several proposed solutions, but none of the following have worked.

### Unrestrict Editing Document

In almost all search results I found, the first suggestion was to make sure the document has no editing restrictions. I've confirmed this by clicking on the `restrict editing` icon and verified nothing is checked:

[image: Unrestricted Editing]

### Clear Custom Properties

Within the file's `Info Properties → Advanced Properties → Custom` tab, there are no values.
[image]

### Simple Steps

- Confirmed no macros (file saves as `.docx`
- Removed custom XML parts
- Resaved on my local drive

## Other Observations

There's an unusual lock within the image and triple dots to the left which I don't typically recall seeing.

When right-clicking on the image, most editing options are grayed out.

[image]

How can I remove this image?

Comment: On the Review tab, in the Protect group, click Restrict Editing. Do you see in the Restrict Editing task pane, an entry for Stop Protection?

Comment: Workaround: copy all text (not header/footer), paste into a new document.

Comment: Can you post a link to the problem document as saved in OneDrive or DropBox?

Comment: @harrymc, no I do not see it. My screenshot above doesn't quite cover where that would be, but you can see it says "yes, Start Enforcing" which would be opposite setting.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik ... do you really think after I posted all that detail including taking into consideration XML, macros and advanced properties, that I had **not** thought of using copy-paste as a viable workaround? The document is mostly blank in the body section --  what iI need is quite a bit of the behind-the-scenes components (i.e. styles). Ultimately I'll probably have to do it all manually or with a macro which will be a pain, but will work (also I'm also just genuinely curious what this is...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-word-message-you-cant-make-this-change/341971aa-ec61-4984-8af2-105c2032bb56) says this message can come up in some other cases you haven't covered yet (though most of these would apply to the whole document):

- The object or shape is a Control or part of a Template. Try and delete it in Design Mode (under the Developer tab).
- A **Group** content control has been applied to part or all of the document. Click Developer > Group > Ungroup.
- Your Office is not activated, you are using a trial version of Office that has expired, or you have multiple installations of Office and one is not activated.
- Another user is editing the file.
- The document has been marked as "Final" in File > Info > Protect Document > Mark as final

Comment: ***Boom!*** Throwing it in design mode allowed me to nuke it! I'm not quite sure why, but nice find and thanks!

Comment: So indeed the fix was related to content control (which I hadn't thought of for an image). Once in design mode, i had the full ability to edit/delete/resize. However if one were to right click on the image (while still in design mode) and click *remove content control*, the image behaves normally outside of design mode. Thanks again.